# Multiple v-binds - child component - API calls - Vuejs

Tags: javascript, api, data-binding, components, vuejs3

(I'm a beginner in both Vuejs and API handling)
I'm currently working with a crypto currency API and trying to call a property (from a child component to create a list) showing me the evolution of a coin upon 24hours/7days/30days.
The issue is that in order to access the data containing these objects and property I have to make a call to a different url:

- 24h : https://api.coinranking.com/v2/coins
- 7d : https://api.coinranking.com/v2/coins?timePeriod=7d
- 30d : https://api.coinranking.com/v2/coins?timePeriod=30d

However, since I have to make a get request to those URLs in order to collect its data and store it every time, it means I have 3 different places where each info is stored.
I'm able to bind the data from the first one and send it to the child but would like to do so for the 2 others also.
I tried many ways but cannot find a way to make multiple binds (one for each: 24h/7d/30d).

Here's my current code:

```
const proxyUrl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/"

const coins_url = "https://api.coinranking.com/v2/coins"
const coins_url_7d = "https://api.coinranking.com/v2/coins?timePeriod=7d"
const coins_url_30d = "https://api.coinranking.com/v2/coins?timePeriod=30d"


const access_token = 'hidden content'

const reqHeaders = {
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'x-access-token',
        'x-access-token': `token ${access_token}`
    }
}

export default {
    name: 'HomeResults',
    data(){
        return {
            limit: 5,
            cryptoList: [],
            detail: null,
            globVol24: null,
            totalCoins: null,
            marketCap: null,
            evol7d: null,
            evol30d: null
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        //COINS DATA
        axios
        .get(proxyUrl + coins_url, { 
            reqHeaders
        })
        .then((reponseCoins) => {
            // console.log(reponseCoins.data)
            //COINS DATA: this is where I store the first data (24h)
            this.cryptoList = reponseCoins.data.data.coins;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error)
        })


        // EVOLUTION 7 DAYS
        axios
        .get(proxyUrl + coins_url_7d, { 
            reqHeaders
        })
        .then((reponse7d) => {
            console.log(reponse7d.data)
           // this is where I store the first data (7d)
            this.evol7d = reponse7d.data.data.coins;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error)
        })

        // EVOLUTION 30 DAYS
        axios
        .get(proxyUrl + coins_url_30d, { 
            reqHeaders
        })
        .then((reponse30d) => {
            console.log(reponse30d.data)
            // this is where I store the first data (30d)
            this.evol30d = reponse30d.data.data.coins;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error)
        }),
       computed: {
        // Limiting results showing
        limitCryptoRes: function() {
            return this.limit ? this.cryptoList.slice(0, this.limit) : this.cryptoList;
        }
      },
      components: {
        'cryptoItem' : CryptoItem
      }
}
```

Then I bind the data to my component :

```
<tr v-bind:key="index" v-for="(detail, index) in limitCryptoRes">
    <cryptoItem 
     v-bind:cryptoList="detail"
     class="mt-1 mb-1 pt-3 pb-3 pl-3 pr-3"></cryptoItem>
</tr>
```

I have tried several ways to bind `cryptoList`,  `evol7d` and  `evol30d` but couldn't make it.
I'm clearly missing something here...

If you need extra info, don't hesitate.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: i'm seeing that you are cycling a limitCryptoRes, but i can't find in your code, is missing some code? meanwhile, instead of call constant above data, a little tips is to make a file.js, export, and then import what you need in your vue file

Comment: @Dario no it's indeed not missing, I just didn't add it in the code as it seemed unnecessary but I added it anyway in my original post.

Comment: I'll also look into your advice of file.js for constants, If i can make my code cleaner it's a good thing, thanks!

Comment: Hi @jerephens, i'm not totally clear on what you are trying to achieve but here's a codesandbox that might help. https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-gareth-wl2hk?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: @colin thanks for this link it's great! it'll help me get things cleaner but my issue is more about how to transfer the data from those 3 requests to the child component as I can only add one data-binding (v-bind) to the component (as far as I've seen), might try to store them all in the same table (cryptoList) but I don't think that's gonna work.

Answer (score 2):

I've shared some code over at codesandbox for a live example
https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-gareth-wl2hk?file=/src/App.vue:0-3578

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <label>Crypto</label>
    <select>
      <option
        v-for="crypto in limitCryptoRes.list"
        v-bind:key="crypto.name"
        v-bind:value="crypto.name"
      >
        {{ crypto.name }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label> 7 day - 24 hour volume </label>
    <select>
      <option
        v-for="crypto in limitCryptoRes.evol7d"
        v-bind:key="crypto['24hVolume']"
        v-bind:value="crypto['24hVolume']"
      >
        {{ `${crypto.name}: ${crypto["24hVolume"]}` }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label> 30 day - Price</label>
    <select>
      <option
        v-for="crypto in limitCryptoRes.evol30d"
        v-bind:key="crypto.price"
        v-bind:value="crypto.price"
      >
        {{ `${crypto.name}: ${crypto.price}` }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <pre>{{ JSON.stringify(limitCryptoRes.list, null, 2) }}</pre>
  <h3>7d results</h3>
  <pre>{{ JSON.stringify(limitCryptoRes.evol7d, null, 2) }}</pre>
  <h3>30d results</h3>
  <pre>{{ JSON.stringify(limitCryptoRes.evol30d, null, 2) }}</pre>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
const proxyUrl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";

const coins_url = "https://api.coinranking.com/v2/coins";
const coins_url_7d = "https://api.coinranking.com/v2/coins?timePeriod=7d";
const coins_url_30d = "https://api.coinranking.com/v2/coins?timePeriod=30d";

const access_token = "hidden content";

const reqHeaders = {
  headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "x-access-token",
    "x-access-token": `token ${access_token}`,
  },
};
export default {
  name: "HomeResults",
  data() {
    return {
      limit: 5,
      cryptoList: {
        list: [],
        evol7d: [],
        evol30d: [],
      },
      detail: null,
      globVol24: null,
      totalCoins: null,
      marketCap: null,
      evol7d: null,
      evol30d: null,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    limitCryptoRes: function () {
      return {
        list: this.cryptoList.list.slice(0, this.limit),
        evol7d: this.cryptoList.evol7d.slice(0, this.limit),
        evol30d: this.cryptoList.evol30d.slice(0, this.limit),
      };
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    //COINS DATA
    axios
      .get(proxyUrl + coins_url, {
        reqHeaders,
      })
      .then((reponseCoins) => {
        // console.log(reponseCoins.data)
        //COINS DATA: this is where I store the first data (24h)
        this.cryptoList.list = reponseCoins.data.data.coins;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });

    // EVOLUTION 7 DAYS
    axios
      .get(proxyUrl + coins_url_7d, {
        reqHeaders,
      })
      .then((reponse7d) => {
        console.log(reponse7d.data);
        // this is where I store the first data (7d)
        this.cryptoList.evol7d = reponse7d.data.data.coins;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });

    // EVOLUTION 30 DAYS
    axios
      .get(proxyUrl + coins_url_30d, {
        reqHeaders,
      })
      .then((reponse30d) => {
        console.log(reponse30d.data);
        // this is where I store the first data (30d)
        this.cryptoList.evol30d = reponse30d.data.data.coins;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

pre {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

label {
  display: block;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time m8!
I totally get what you did except (and I edited my initial question because it wasn't obvious enough) : I'm just not able to send the info to a component (child)... I haven't found the way to do so yet (like you here, how do I bind the data in those 3 tables into one v-bind in the component html tag.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to iterate over `limitCryptoRes` which computes from `cryptoList`. But the only place where you add data to `cryptoList` is the first get request.

You need to push **each** response from those request to to the `cryptoList` array, like this:

```
axios.get(proxyUrl + coins_url, { reqHeaders })
  .then((responseCoins) => {
    this.cryptoList.push(reponseCoins.data.data.coins)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err)
  })
```

Comment: The problem is if I do that that I'll have 3 arrays in the same array and then I'm not able to get the specific info I want when in the child. Will keep trying though.

Comment: btw I did what you say but do you have any input on how to iterate through this array which then contains 3 other arrays of objects?